# PHP&MySQL - How to determine which table a result is from

Tags: php, sql, database, mysqli

I have the following code that searches two different tables in my database.

```
$defaultQuery = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT fullname, company, id FROM employees WHERE company = '$topCID' AND `id` != '$eid' UNION ALL SELECT fullname, company, id FROM users WHERE company = '$topCID' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6");
```

Is there a way to create an if statement in my results to say "IF this result is from EMPLOYEES, ECHO the letter "e". IF this result is from USERS, echo the letter "u"."?

Comment: Add a column in both selects with a constant value ("e" / "u").

Comment: @PM77-1 can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

As I said, just ad an extra column:

```
SELECT fullname, company, id, 'e' as `Source`
FROM employees 
WHERE company = '$topCID' AND `id` != '$eid' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT fullname, company, id, 'u' 
FROM users 
WHERE company = '$topCID' 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 6
```